# Unable to create mysql triggers

Tags: mysql

every time I create a trigger, I get the following error even when I don't use system tables.

```
ERROR 1465 (HY000): Triggers can not be created on system tables
```

Here is my sample test

```
select * from student
    -> ;
+------------+---------+------+---------+
| name       | roll_no | dept | dept_no |
+------------+---------+------+---------+
| diya       | xxzz50  |    5 |      20 |
```

roll_no is the primary key .

and when I execute

```
create trigger sample before delete on student for each row insert into temp values(roll_no,name);
```

I get the error

```
ERROR 1465 (HY000): Triggers can not be created on system tables.
```

Can someone please help me . where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to make the trigger in the default `mysql` database...?

What is the name of the database that your table `student` is located in?  Maybe test?

```
create trigger test.sample 
   before delete on student for each row insert into temp values(roll_no,name);
```

or... just...

```
create trigger `whatever the name of your database is..?`.`sample` 
   before delete on student for each row insert into temp values(roll_no,name);
```

Comment: @KavyaVishwanathB - if this worked as a solution to your problem, please mark it as answered.